# h:messages does not display messages when p:commandButton is pressed

Tags: jsf, primefaces, message

I have a problem with the h:messages tag in JSF that simply does not show any messages. In the Glassfish log are no errors when I click the button.
The setup is as follows:

test.xhtml:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" 
    xmlns:j="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <title>test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:messages globalOnly="true"/>
    <h:form id="loginform">         
        <p:commandButton id="testButton" value="Test"
          action="#{loginSessionBean.test()}" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

With The SessionScopedBean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class LoginSessionBean implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
...
public String test(){
     FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
     fc.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "Test!", null)); 
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You're sending an ajax request with PrimeFaces `<p:commandButton>`. Ajax requests have by default no form of feedback (unless PrimeFaces' `autoUpdate="true"` is been used somewhere). You should be explicitly specifying parts of the view which you'd like to update on ajax response.

One way is specifying the `update` attribute on `<p:commandButton>` to point to the client ID of the `<h:messages>` component.

```
<h:messages id="messages" ... />
<h:form>         
    <p:commandButton ... update=":messages" />
</h:form>
```

Another way is to replace it by PrimeFaces `<p:messages>` which has an `autoUpdate` attribute for the purpose of automatic update on ajax response.

```
<p:messages ... autoUpdate="true" />
<h:form>         
    <p:commandButton ... />
</h:form>
```

A completely different alternative is to turn off ajax by adding `ajax="false"` attribute to the button, this way a synchronous postback will be performed which effectively results in a full page update, exactly like as how the standard JSF `<h:commandButton>` behaves when used without `<f:ajax>`.

```
<h:messages ... />
<h:form>         
    <p:commandButton ... ajax="false" />
</h:form>
```

#### See also:

- [Understanding PrimeFaces process/update and JSF f:ajax execute/render attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-process-and-update-attributes-of-primefaces/)

Comment: I've lost some hours because p:inputMask ignores all rules