# Don't show JSF messages on top of the page

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm showing my validation messages on my jsf page:

```
  <h:outputLabel value="Nome"/>
                    <h:inputText id="idNome" value="#{cadastrarClienteMB.cliT.nome}" required="true" requiredMessage="Digite o Nome para continuar!"/>
                    <h:message style="color:red; font-size:10px;" for="idNome"/>
```

Okay, it's working. This is great for me. The big problem is that the validation messages is showing at the top of the page.

How to not showing messages at the top?

Thanks.

Comment: an `h:message` message shows where **you** put it. Either directly or via css. So check all that

Comment: This is not the default behavior. Problem is not visible in the information provided so far. When we copy'n'paste the snippet and then stub/autogenerate the missing parts with sane defaults/code as documented, then everything works perfectly fine for us all. As an educated guess I'd say you're sending an ajax request and you not updating the specific message, is this correct? If so, then this is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16175178